# Disable Specific Date and all Dates before it

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-5, eonasdan-datetimepicker

I am using the [datetimepicker](http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/#enableddisabled-dates) and I want to disable a specific date from the controller and all dates before it.

So how do I pass the date from the controller to the datetimepicker?

Here is what I mean:

```
MRecord firstMR = db.MRecords.Where(x => x.AID == dSum.AircraftID).OrderBy(x => x.DateEntered).FirstOrDefault();

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('#datetimepicker5').datetimepicker({
            disabledDates: [
                // how do I disable all dates before and including firstMR.DateEntered?
            ]
        });
    });
    </script>
```

Is it possible to do this all in the view?  I am using razor.

Any help is appreciated.

**UPDATE**

I am trying this in Razor View:

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Create";
    var firstMR = new ALogSummary.Models.MRecord();

    using (var db = new AviationLogSummary.Models.ALogsEntities())
    {
        firstMR = db.MRecords.Where(x => x.AID == Model.AID).OrderBy(x => x.DateEntered).FirstOrDefault();
    }

}



<div id="datetimepicker2" class="input-group date">
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Day, new { htmlAttributes = new { id = "Day", @class = "form-control" } })
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Day, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        <span class="input-group-addon">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
        </span>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('#datetimepicker2').datetimepicker({
            format: 'MM/DD/YYYY HH:mm',
            minDate: [@firstMR.DateEntered.Date]
        });
    });
 </script>
```

I am receiving this error when I debug:

> JavaScript critical error at line 160, column 49 in http://localhost:xxxxx/DSummaries/Create/7\n\nSCRIPT1007: Expected ']'

**UPDATE 2**:

```
<div id="datetimepicker2" class="input-group date" >
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Day, new { htmlAttributes = new { id = "Day", @class = "form-control", data_mindate = firstMR.DateEntered.Date } })
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Day, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    <span class="input-group-addon">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
    </span>
</div>
```

**SCRIPT:**

This is in it's own JS file

```
$(function () {
    $('#datetimepicker2').datetimepicker({
        format: 'MM/DD/YYYY HH:mm',
        minDate: $(this).data('mindate')
    });
});
```

The HTML output is:

```
<input class="form-control text-box single-line valid" id="Day" type="datetime" data-val-required="This field is required!" data-val="true" data-mindate="05/28/2016 00:00:00" data-val-date="This field: must be a date." value="06/28/2016 09:07"></input>
```

so the correct mindate is being populated but my script isn't working.

Comment: Why not just use the `minDate` option (and set it to the value of `firstMR.DateEntered`)?

Comment: @StephenMuecke I have updated my question.  Is that what you were suggesting?

Comment: Remove the square brackets (`minDate` is a value, not an array of values.

Comment: @StephenMuecke ahh that worked plus, I had to put `' '` around the `@firstMR.DateEntered`.  if you put your answer down I will mark as accepted

Comment: @StephenMuecke All of my scripts are in their own seperate JS file... now to make this work I had to move that Script into that exact view in order to get it to work along side with Razor functionality.. is there a way to get that `firstMR.DateEntered` value to the JS file where this script was originally?

Comment: Lots of ways. For example, create a global var in the main view, but best to put a `date-*` attribute in the element - `new { htmlAttributes = new { data_mindate = firstMR.DateEntered.Date, ..... }` and then in the script `minDate: $(this).data('mindate')`. But in any case you should get rid of that query in the view and do that in the controller and assign the value to a view model property.

Comment: @StephenMuecke I updated my question again. I have tried what you suggested and the mindate in the HTML output is being populated correctly, but my script isn't getting the mindate

Comment: Should work fine - but try `$(function () { var mindate = $('#datetimepicker2').data('mindate'); $('#datetimepicker2').datetimepicker({ ... minDate" mindate }); })`

Comment: Okay, that worked. thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than using the `disabledDates` options, use the `minDate` option to prevent users selecting dates before the `minDate` value

```
$('#datetimepicker2').datetimepicker({
    format: 'MM/DD/YYYY HH:mm',
    minDate: '@firstMR.DateEntered.Date'
});
```

Since this script is in an external js file (and razor code is not parsed in external files), you can pass the value using a `data-*` attribute on your element

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Day, new { htmlAttributes = new { data_mindate = firstMR.DateEntered.Date, @class = "form-control" } })
```

Note there is no need to include `id = "Day"` since that's already added by the `EditorFor()` method (and you appear to have made a typo anyway since the script refers to an element with `id="datetimepicker2"`).

Then in the external file

```
var day = $('#Day')
day.datetimepicker({
    format: 'MM/DD/YYYY HH:mm',
    minDate: day.data('mindate')
});
```